# XCode 4 - Build error "missing required architecture i386 in file"

Tags: objective-c, xcode4

I'm getting this error when trying to compile my project.

What could be causing this? Basically I'm trying to use the barcode generator library from here http://www.onbarcode.com/tutorial/iphone-barcode-generator-guide.html

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-LOnBarcode/Release-iphonesimulator/usr/local/include'
ld: warning: ignoring file /path/OnBarcode/3.2/Release-iphoneos/libOnBarcodeIPhone.a, missing required architecture i386 in file
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_OBLinear", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in MyViewBarcode.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I added the path in my header and library path. Although I need to clarify, how should the path look like if I'm doing it relative? (i.e ./path/name)

This is how my directory structure look on the filesystem:

Project
|-> OnBarcode

Should it be "./OnBarcode"?

Also yes I have read similar posts but those are more framework related and not library related.

Thank you,
Tee

Comment: Just to add to this. The project compiles fine to a device. So the issue is with compiling to a simulator.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are referencing the correct libOnBarcodeIPhone.a for the simulator. It is located in the Release-iphonesimulator folder, otherwise if you are bulding for the device then reference the Release-iphoneos